# Why equals and "==" doesn`t work when i want to get data from arrayList using for loop?

Tags: java

```
import java.util.ArrayList;

public class Main {
        public static void main(String[] args) {
        ArrayList<Integer> list = new ArrayList<>();
        for (int i = 0; i < 10000000; i++) {
            list.add(i);
        }
        Integer n = 5000000;
        boolean contains = true;
        for (int i = 0; i < 10000000; i++) {
            if (list.get(i).equals(n))
                contains = true;
            else
                contains = false;

        }
        System.out.println(contains);

        contains = list.contains(5000000);
        System.out.println(contains);
    }

}
```

I have a question why the second loop returns false when i want to find an equal n value. The same thing happens when i use "==" or "equals()" method.

When i use Collection method "contains()" it is woking and it returns "true".

Second question, is the fastest way to get data (for example my variable "n") from list by using "contains()" or there is better (faster) way to do this?

Comment: because you do not stop your loop when you found the element in there. In the next iteration your contains variable might be set to false again. Add a `break;` after `contains=true;` and you are done.

Comment: if all you need to know is if the element is there, you could consider using a set or map instead of a list. The would be a lot faster.

Comment: @chatton thanks for answer. I ill learn about data acces from various list types. I think iterating through all list length is not good idea when i looking for fastest way. Is "contains()" method faster than loop and or maybe there is fastest way ?

Comment: I always find it useful to look at source code http://www.docjar.com/html/api/java/util/ArrayList.java.html have a look at the contains and indexOf methods.

Answer (score 2):

You have not break the loop even if it found the match. After found the match contains is true, then for the next iteration if not match you are resetting `contains = false`

Also you can simplify it.

```
boolean contains = false;
for (int i = 0; i < 10000000; i++) {
    if (list.get(i).equals(n)) {
        contains = true;
        break;
    }
}
```

By the way ArrayList contains method have time complexity O(n), Where n is the number of element. You can use HashSet, It doesn't have any order but it's contains method time complexity only O(1)

Example :

```
HashSet<Integer> set = new HashSet<>();
for (int i = 0; i < 10000000; i++) {
    set.add(i);
}

Integer n = 5000000;
System.out.println(set.contains(n));
```

Comment: Thank you all for your answers! It is obvious now for me, i made a silly mistake.

Answer (score 0):

Because even when `i` was equal to `n` and `contain` got `true` Value, you reassigned `false` value to it again in the next iteration, you shouldn't use `else` :

```
import java.util.ArrayList;

    public class Main {
            public static void main(String[] args) {
            ArrayList<Integer> list = new ArrayList<>();
            for (int i = 0; i < 10000000; i++) {
                list.add(i);
            }
            Integer n = 5000000;
            boolean contains = false;
            for (int i = 0; i < 10000000; i++) {
                if (list.get(i).equals(n))
                    contains = true;
                    break;

            }
            System.out.println(contains);

            contains = list.contains(5000000);
            System.out.println(contains);
        }

    }
```

Comment: You have to initialze `boolean contains = false;`. Otherswise with your changes there is no chance for contains ever to become false.

Comment: Silly mistake from me !